# How to use Multiple Paint Components at the same time in java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm making a GUI with java which represents the Longest Path Problem I'm using Graphics 2D to draw the vertices and the links between them. I've made a button which calculates the longest path between two vertices I want to make a link that grows slowly so, I've used Thread.sleep() method to make that but when I use it the whole program becomes very slow and lagging.
I've Overriden the paintComponent method to draw and I can't use Multi threading because that makes problems with EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).
I've saw other topics for Multiple paint Components but nothing helped me.Any ideas or help??

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{   
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(!dragging&&MainFrame.ActiveAddNode)
    g.drawRect(X,Y, 20, 20);//Virtual rectangle for the vertex
    p=new Polygon();
    for(int i=0;i<Node.size();i++)
    {
        p.addPoint(Node.get(i).X+10, Node.get(i).Y+10);
        g.setColor(Node.get(i).c);
        g.fillRect(Node.get(i).X, Node.get(i).Y, 20, 20);//represents the graph vertex
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.drawString(""+i, Node.get(i).X+7,  Node.get(i).Y+15);//the number of the vertex

    }
for(int i=0;i<Node.size();i++)
    for(int j=0;j<Node.get(i).Children.size();j++){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        for(int k=0;k<link.size()-1;k++)
        {
            if(link.get(k)==i&&link.get(k+1)==Node.get(i).Children.get(j)){
                g.setColor(Color.RED);//Highlight the Longest path link
            }
        }

        g.drawLine(Node.get(i).X+10, Node.get(i).Y+10, Node.get(Node.get(i).Children.get(j)).X+10
                ,  Node.get(Node.get(i).Children.get(j)).Y+10);
        int Xsum=(Node.get(i).X+Node.get(Node.get(i).Children.get(j)).X)/2;
        int Ysum=(Node.get(i).Y+Node.get(Node.get(i).Children.get(j)).Y)/2;
        g.drawString(""+Node.get(i).Edges.get(j),Xsum,Ysum);

    }//end of 2nd loop
}//end of paint component
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've used Thread.sleep()

Don't use `Thread.sleep(...)` when code is executing on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. This will prevent the GUI from painting itself.

The point of the `paintComponent(...)` method is to paint the current state of the component.

So you need a method(s) that will allow you to dynamically alter the state of the component. So maybe you have a property like: `setPathLength(...)`. So once you calculate the longest path you know how many iterations are required to display the entire path.

Then you need to use a `Timer` to schedule your animation. Every time the `Timer` fires you need to increase the "path length" by 1 and then repaint() your component. So each time one more node is painted.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me toooooooo much. You're genius